# How to randomly select questions from a list?

Tags: r

I have developed questions and answers for a quiz. It is a list with more than 50 questions. Now, I need to randomly pick questions from the list. The selection should be based on the topic, skill level and difficulty level (mentioned as diff in the list).

Since, I am a novice r programmer a detailed explanation will help me to develop my skills.

Thanks in advance

This is one sample question:

```
new <- list(question="What is name of the tallest building in the world?", 
    answers=list(
      c("(a) Empire state",0),
      c("(b) Shanghai Tower",0),
      c("(c) Abraj Al-Bait Clock Tower",0),
      c("(d) Burj Khalifa",1),
      c("(e) None of the above",0)),
    diff=NA,
    topic='General Knowledge',
    skill=NA,
    using=TRUE,
    id=10
),
```

Comment: Read `?sample`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation NelsonGon. Do you have any example code to show how to sample from a list based on some conditions?

Comment: There's only one diff entry which is set to NA. How exactly do you want to use this? I would think using  a data frame would make the manipulation easier?

Comment: Skill level of the student who attend the quiz? Sometimes the questions can suit the beginners or experts. At the moment, I have not classified any questions like that, so I kept it as NA. In case of the difficulty level, I am planning to update it based on the mean right answers across the group. If 90% of them got it right - it will indicate it the easiest question. Later, I will update this information to the list. That will allow me to use that conditions for the new students batch to distribute questions based on different difficulty level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to choose an arbitrary entry from a list you could use the following where question_list is a list of question. The `sample()` function is choosing a random integer from 1 to the length of the question_list and the `[]` are calling that result in the list.

```
question_list[sample(1:length(question_list),1)]
```

Comment: This one is working completely fine. Thanks for your valuable suggestion Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can do a random select based on criteria using this code below.

```
# Create sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  question = c("What is", "Who is", "Where is"),
  answera = c("i", "j", "k"),
  answerb = c("l", "m", "n"),
  answerc = c("o", "p", "q"),
  topic = c("geography", "geography", "history"),
  skill = c("low", "high", "high")
  )

# Option 1 - Filter list based on topic and skill
subset(df, select = c('question','answera','answerb','answerc'), topic == 'geography' & skill == 'low')

# Option 2 - Randomly select two questions
df[sample(nrow(df), 2), ]

# Option 3 - Filter and then randomly select
filtered <- subset(df, select = c('question','answera','answerb','answerc'), topic == 'geography')
filtered[sample(nrow(filtered ), 1), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is useful if I have created a dataframe. But I have every single question in the list. I am trying to pick only few questions randomly from the list - but failed to accomplish it.